# I lost video sound when using Overlay Video + Chroma key with FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I have run a piece of code with the following command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i green.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]colorkey=0x3BBD1E:0.3:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]" -map "[out]" output.mp4
```

[image]

The code runs normally, but the output video output has no sound.

What happened?

Note:

- video "input.mp4" has sound.
- the video "green.mp4" sound or no sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to map the audio. After `-map "[out]"`,  add `-map 0:a`

Comment: @Gyan : Hi Gyan, I have a question, can you help me? with the above ffmpeg code (video file GREEN.MP4) I want it to be able to repeat with (video INPUT.MP4) ?
In this case, how do we change the above code?

Comment: The video "green.mp4" can loop with INPUT video? ( Green.mp4 = 59s....; Input.mp4 = 15s)

Comment: If you want to repeat input, add `-stream_loop -1` before `-i` and add `-shortest` before output name.

Comment: @Gyan I want to repeat GREEN?